# Constructors for typealiased types using generics

Tags: generics, kotlin, type-alias

I am learning Kotlin at the moment.

But I am having trouble with the following example.

When I type alias a class I created myself, I can use the normal constructor as seen below, but I cannot do the same thing with the Kotlin list type. What am I missing here?

```
class Example<T> {}

typealias Ex<T> = Example<T> // typealias for example class
typealias L<T> = List<T> // typealias for Kotlin list class

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Ex<Int>() // OK! compiles
    L<Int>(0,{ _ -> 1}) // unresolved reference
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `List<T>` is an interface, which means there is no constructors. and the [typealias](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html#type-aliases) keyword is used for existing types.  In fact, `List(size,init)` is defined as a top-level extension function in `stdlib` as below:

```
//             v--- List(size){...} is a function rather than a type
inline fun <T> List(size:Int, init: (index: Int)->T):List<T>=MutableList(size,init)
```

**IF** you change the alias `L` to the **concrete** class `ArrayList`, you found you also can create it by use its constructor, for example:

```
typealias L<T> = ArrayList<T> 

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // v--- create `L<Int>` by its constructor
    L<Int>(1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I assumed It was a class instead of an interface. I didn't know it was possible to create a function that looks like a Constructor

Comment: @TobiahLissens Not at all. glad it helped you, :)